# Keeping a seperate file for path of all the images

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have to use many different images into my windows phone application. Although I have maintained a separate folder for images inside the application, I want to maintain some XML or properties where I can save the path of all those images and then call them from that particular place. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Resource item for that purpose. In **Add New Item** you can find **Resources File** item. You can use this resource item to manage *Strings,Images,Icons,Audio,Files* and any other content....